# Объединение записей с одним идентификатором

Tags: php, mysql, циклы

Есть цикл `foreach`, который заполняет поля на форме из таблицы по следующему запросу из БД:
`$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblOrder INNER JOIN tblOrderProduct ON tblOrderProduct.OrderID=tblOrder.OrderID INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tblOrderProduct.ProductID=tblProduct.ProductID WHERE tblOrder.CustomerID ='$customerid'");`

таблица `tblOrderProduct` имеет вид типа:
`|OrderID||ProductID|
 |1      ||1        |
 |1      ||2        |`

Т.е. в одном заказе может быть несколько продуктов. Так вот проблема возникает когда я пытаюсь в цикле заполнить поля. **Мне необходимо запихнуть значения с одинаковым `OrderID` в один div**, чтобы информация о продукте шла друг за другом в пределе этого diva, но у меня создается отдельные divы в результате чего информация о продуктах разделяется. **Как мне добиться такого объединения?**
Заполняю поля на странице так:

```
<?php foreach ($_SESSION['orders'] as $orders): ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">

            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $orders["OrderID"];?>">Номер заказа #<?php echo $orders["OrderID"];?><div class="pull-right"><?php echo $orders["DateOrder"]; ?></div></a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse<?php echo $orders["OrderID"];?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Название</td>
                    <td>Кол-во</td>
                    <td>Цена</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $orders["ProductName"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $orders["Quality"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $orders["TotalSum"];?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Результат var_dumb()**:
    `array(6) { [0]=> array(6) { ["OrderID"]=> string(2) "22" ["ProductID"]=> string(1) "3" ["ProductName"]=> string(67) "Котел твердотопливный ZOTA Carbon 32 уголь" ["Quality"]=> string(1) "1" ["DateOrder"]=> string(10) "2016-06-05" ["TotalSum"]=> string(4) "5000" } [1]=> array(6) { ["OrderID"]=> string(2) "23" ["ProductID"]=> string(1) "7" ["ProductName"]=> string(67) "Котел твердотопливный ZOTA Carbon 32 уголь" ["Quality"]=> string(1) "2" ["DateOrder"]=> string(10) "2016-06-06" ["TotalSum"]=> string(5) "10334" } [2]=> array(6) { ["OrderID"]=> string(2) "23" ["ProductID"]=> string(1) "6" ["ProductName"]=> string(34) "Автомат 1П 01А ABB S201C1" ["Quality"]=> string(1) "1" ["DateOrder"]=> string(10) "2016-06-06" ["TotalSum"]=> string(5) "10334" } [3]=> array(6) { ["OrderID"]=> string(2) "24" ["ProductID"]=> string(1) "4" ["ProductName"]=> string(32) "Стартер S10 4-65W Philips" ["Quality"]=> string(1) "1" ["DateOrder"]=> string(10) "2016-06-09" ["TotalSum"]=> string(4) "7334" } [4]=> array(6) { ["OrderID"]=> string(2) "24" ["ProductID"]=> string(1) "6" ["ProductName"]=> string(34) "Автомат 1П 01А ABB S201C1" ["Quality"]=> string(1) "1" ["DateOrder"]=> string(10) "2016-06-09" ["TotalSum"]=> string(4) "7334" } [5]=> array(6) { ["OrderID"]=> string(2) "24" ["ProductID"]=> string(1) "7" ["ProductName"]=> string(67) "Котел твердотопливный ZOTA Carbon 32 уголь" ["Quality"]=> string(1) "1" ["DateOrder"]=> string(10) "2016-06-09" ["TotalSum"]=> string(4) "7334" } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует изначально полученный массив продуктов преобразовать в массив `"заказ"` -> `"продукты в заказе"`. Т.е. пробегаете в цикле исходный массив и формируете массив вида:

```
[
    'OrderID_1' => [
        'ProductID_1_1',
        'ProductID_1_2',
        ...
        'ProductID_1_N',
    ],
    ...
    'OrderID_M' => [
        'ProductID_M_1',
        'ProductID_M_2',
        ...
        'ProductID_M_N',
    ],
]
```

А уже такой массив без всяких проблем можете выводить в таблицу, как вам и нужно. Там будет два цикла - внешним пробегаетесь по ордерам и выводите `div`, а внутренним циклом внутри `div`-а выводите продукты.

**Обновление**

Судя по тому, что у вас есть в коде, предположу, что структура массива примерно такая:

```
[
    ["OrderID", "ProductID", "ProductName", "TotalSum", "Quality"],
    ...
]
```

Привести его к требуемому виду можно так:

```
$result = array();

foreach($orders as $order) {
    if (!isset($result[$order['OrderID']])) {
        $result[$order['OrderID']] = array();
    }

    $result[$order['OrderID']][] = $order;
}
```

**Обновление 2**

Вот ваш код с требуемыми преобразованиями. Естественно, на данных не тестировался, потому проверить и исправить ошибки, если есть, можете сами.

```
<?php if (!empty($_SESSION['orders'])): ?>

<?php
    $orderMap = array();

    foreach($_SESSION['orders'] as $order) {
        if (!isset($orderMap[$order['OrderID']])) {
            $orderMap[$order['OrderID']] = array(
                'products'  => array(),
                'date'      => $order['DateOrder']
            );
        }

        $orderMap[$order['OrderID']]['products'][] = $order;
    }
?>

<?php foreach ($orderMap as $orderId => $orderData): ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?=$orderId;?>">Номер заказа #<?=$orderId;?><div class="pull-right"><?=$orderData["date"]; ?></div></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse<?=$orderId;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Название</td>
                        <td>Кол-во</td>
                        <td>Цена</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($orderData['products'] as $product): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?=$product["ProductName"];?></td>
                            <td><?=$product["Quality"];?></td>
                            <td><?=$product["TotalSum"];?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Сколько ни пытался так и не понял как это сделать... Ведь мне помимо `ProductID` нужно еще другие поля получать.

Comment: Ну я ведь только примерно указал структуру. Если вам не сложно, добавьте в вопрос, как выглядит одна запись из вашего массива, который вы выводите. А я тогда попробую обновить ответ.

Comment: подскажите, вот так я правильно преобразую массив или нет?`foreach ($order as $key => $value){
              $orderProd1= array($key['OrderID']=>$value['ProductID']);

           }`

Comment: Думаю, нет. Как минимум, $orderProd1 вы постоянно перезаписываете.

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Comment: Все равно не работает, совсем не могу понять как сделать. Массив `$result` пытаюсь вывести в цикле мне выдает кучу ошибок. Где-то  есть вообще пример посмотреть? весь интернет облазил ничего кроме общей информации не нашел.

Comment: Как вы пытаетесь `$result` использовать?

Comment: Пытаюсь в цикле его вывести вот так: `<?php foreach ($_SESSION['result'] as $result): ?>` далее в заголовке дива ставлю `<?php echo $result["OrderID"];?>` но там пусто. В сессии у меня массив `result`.

Comment: Попробуйте код из ответа, замените ваш первоначальный. Если в сессии есть массив `orders` и структура его такая, как и предполагалось, то должно работать. Ошибки, если есть, сами поправьте, я его не тестировал. Если все равно что-то кардинально не так, то проверяйте входные данные, больше некуда копать.

Comment: Спасибо большое! В div-е так и выводит по одному продукту, к сожалению, буду сидеть думать как поправить, больше не буду вас мучить...

Comment: А сделайте `var_dump($orderMap)`. Код из **обновления 2** гарантированно выведет несколько продуктов (если их несколько в данных).

Comment: сделал `var_dump($orderMap)` и `var_dump($_SESSION['orders'])` в первом случае выводит по одному продукту в заказе (?), а в сессию попадает нужное кол-во.

Comment: А попробуйте сейчас код из **Обновление 2**

Comment: в `foreach` переменную которая была я первым делом на сессию заменил, к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Добавьте результат `var_dump($_SESSION['orders'])` в ваш вопрос. `var_dump` сделайте непосредственно перед этой строчкой: `$orderMap = array();`. У вас явно что-то с данными не так, но вы их так и не показали. Если данные ок, то будет работать.

Comment: У меня была опечатка, попробуйте обновленный код. На ваших данных у меня всё работает.

Comment: Да! Все работает, спасибо Вам еще раз!